# Методы расширения LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Есть список товаров `List<Product>`, в котором `Product` имеет свойства стоимость `Cost` и группа `Group`. Можете привести пример как использовать метод расширения, чтобы получить товар, к примеру самый дорогой  (но не ниже стоимости 50$) по каждой группе? Спасибо.

```
var rez = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>>();

foreach (var pr in rez)
{
   if (pr.Value > 50)
   {
      List<Product> prodByGroup;
      if (!rez.TryGetValue(p.Group, out prodByGroup))
      {
          prodByGroup = new List<Product>();
          rez.Add(p.Group, prodByGroup);
      }

      prodByGroup.Add(pr);
  } 
}
```

Comment: какой метод расширения? В чем трудности?

Comment: var group1Result = products.Where(x => x.Cost > 50 && x.Group == "Группа 1"); имеется ввиду что-то вроде этого?

Comment: Да, именно это.

Comment: Оформил как ответ

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Общий совет: не торопитесь использовать циклы. Постарайтесь выразить LINQ выши намеренья и только если это неестественно выглядит или вообще невыразимо LINQ, тогда циклы и стоит применять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// группируем
var topProducts = products.GroupBy(product => product.Group)
    // фильтруем группы по цене каждого более 50
    .Where(grouped => grouped.All(product => product.Price > 50))
    // извлекаем самый дорогой
    .Select(grouped => grouped.OrderByDescending(g => g.Price).First())
```

Затем можно добавить `ToList` или `ToArray` по вкусу.

### UPDATE

Для данного случая ещё проще будет сперва отфильтровать, затем сгруппировать

```
// фильтруем по цене
var topProducts = products.Where(product => product.Price > 50)
    // группируем
    .GroupBy(grouped => grouped.Group)
    // извлекаем самый дорогой
    .Select(grouped => grouped.OrderByDescending(g => g.Price).First())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var grpups = products.Select(o => o.Group).Distinct();
var result = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>>();
foreach(var mygroup in groups)
{
  result.Add(mygroup, products.Where(x => x.Cost > 50 && x.Group == mygroup);
}
```

Comment: Я скорректировал вопрос, потому что некорректно задал.

Comment: Как сделать обычным способом - знаю. Но можно ли как-то это получить более приятным для глаз кодом с использованием методов расширения LINQ?

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно с каждой группы выбрать по одному товару, с максимальным значением не меньше 50?

Comment: Да, именно так. В вопросе я привел код, если он что-то даст.

Comment: Не пиши ответ, суть я уловил. Этого достаточно.